# maven war plugin executions and filtering in a multimodule project

Tags: maven-2, maven-war-plugin

I'm using maven to build a multimodule project.

In one project I execute maven-war-plugin four times in order to filter some properties in every execution. As a stand alone project it works well.

But when I build the multimodule, from the "parent" it executes four times, but none of them filter the properties.

Thank you all!

Heres a fragment of my pom.xml:

```
<project>  
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.my</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>myProject</name>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>list</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>war</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>myProj-list.war</warName>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>src/main/filters/list.properties</filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </execution>  
            ...
            <!-- more executions -->
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <includes>
                         <include>**/*.xml</include>
                      </includes>
                </resource>
             </webResources>
             <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/locator.properties</filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: why are you filtering so much?

Comment: well, needs of the project... but it works ok on stand alone but not in module...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I build the multimodule, from the "parent" it executes four times, but none of them filter the properties.

Sounds like a complicated setup... Anyway, are you sure the content of `src/main/webapp` does **not** override the filtered content? Running maven with `-X` might help to debug what is happening.

My suggestion would be to stop abusing **abusing** the `webResources` element (that should be used for  **External** Web Resources) and to move the content that needs to be filtered outside `src/main/webapp`.